# How to create a user in RingCentral account?

Tags: ringcentral

I tried to create a new user in RingCentral account but It is not allowing me to create it. I am using developer Admin account.

Am I missing any privileges?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may be using free account and that's the reason there is not much privilege to create enough users.

You need to go to https://service.devtest.ringcentral.com/application/users/users/

Try the add user--> Add user without device and then try **without number** as below:
[image]

This will work. If you are still unable, then please raise a support ticket.

Hope that helps.